# Using Pandas, how to read a csv file inside a zip file which you fetch using an url[Python]

Tags: python, pandas, zip

This url
https://ihmecovid19storage.blob.core.windows.net/latest/ihme-covid19.zip

contains 2 csv files, and 1 pdf which is updated daily, containing Covid-19 Data.

I want to be able to load the `Summary_stats_all_locs.csv` as a Pandas DataFrame.

Usually if there is a url that points to a csv I can just use `df = pd.read_csv(url)` but since the csv is inside a zip, I can't do that here.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html to see how to extract the file.

Comment: Is there a smart way of doing it without saving the zip to disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to first fetch the file, then load it using the `ZipFile` module. Pandas can read csvs from inside a zip actually, but the problem here is there are multiple, so we need to this and specify the file name.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get("https://ihmecovid19storage.blob.core.windows.net/latest/ihme-covid19.zip")
files = ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))
pd.read_csv(files.open("2020_05_16/Summary_stats_all_locs.csv"))
```